# The term 'dd' is not recognized

Tags: android, windows, cmd, adb, command-prompt

im trying to open/convert .ab to .tar

```
dd if=backup.ab bs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress > backup.tar
```

but i keep getting this error!

```
dd : The term 'dd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

[image]
i want to access backup.ab, but i couldn't convert it to tar. i need help

Answer (score 1):

[`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) command is a GNU command available on Linux/Unix OS.
In Windows `dd` is not included.

If you want to make use of `dd` you have to find a `dd` version for Windows or install a virtual machine with an Linux OS. Since Windows 10 the easiest way is installing a WSL2 (or WSL1) Linux VM. Several systems are available in Microsoft Store for free.

But the more easier way would be to simply use [Android backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) which is a Java based open source tool that can unpack and decrypt Android backup files (´.ab´ to `.tar`).

Comment: how do i install  Android backup extractor on my windows?

Comment: Download the latest `abe.jar` release and execute it like any other Java program: `java-jar abe.jar <program arguments> `. This is also documented in the Android Backup Extractor readme: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/blob/master/README.md